# Non-recursive Version of Min Search

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

`A[x,...,y]` is array of integers and x,y are natural numbers >= 1, and `x <= y`.

```
Foo(Array,x,y)

if (x=y): return Array[x]

else: 
    m=(x+y)/2 
    return min(Foo(Array,x,m), Foo(Array(m+1),y)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write non-recursive version of this piece of code that finds the minimum value in a unsorted array.

I've tried using a while loop where (x != y) but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to move the m until it reaches where x = y and terminates and returns min value. I'm also wondering if it can be done without popping the max value of m and m+1

Comment: The shared solution by you is a recursive approach. What've you tried for the required non-recursive approach?

Comment: I've tried using a while loop where (x != y) but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to move the m until it reaches where x = y and terminates and returns min value

Comment: Do share in the question what you've tried to take a look at it.

Comment: Just so you know, the binary search is as good as linear search because they both are O(n).

Comment: What about this question precludes the standard `if Array[i]<min then min:=Array[i]` approach?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the center of mass of a stick (the point where you can balance it on 1 finger), just hold it up with two fingers at either end, and move them slowly together.

A similar method works for finding the smallest element in an array:

```
findMin(Arr,x,y):

    while(x < y):
        if (Arr[x] < Arr[y])
            y-=1
        else
            x+=1

    return Arr[x]
```

Comment: Nice Analogy - _If you want to find the center of mass of a stick (the point where you can balance it on 1 finger), just hold it up with two fingers at either end, and move them slowly together._

Answer (score 1):

The idea is pretty simple if you just use a stack to hold the pending comparisons. Something like:

```
Func Min(a, x, y)
    min_value = INT_MAX  // largest possible int
    s = empty stack of (x,y) pairs
    s.push(x,y)
    while (!s.isEmpty())
        x,y = s.pop()
        if (x == y)
        {
            if (a[x] < min_value)
                min_value = a[x]
        }
        else
        {
            m = (x+y)/2
            s.push(a, x, m)
            s.push(a, m+1, y)
        }
    }
    return min_value
```

Note that this is a non-recursive translation of your recursive code. It's not at all intended to be a recommendation of how to get the smallest of an array of numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't you start with `INT_MAX`?

Comment: MOehm: yes, I should. Thank you.